# Odoo User and Manager on the same Group

Tags: odoo, customization, odoo-12

I am a beginner in Odoo and I would like to create accounts for Managers and Simple Users respecting these conditions:

- Manager `A` (of the `Team 1`) can see his own records as well as the records of the Users `X1` and `X2`.
- Manager `B` (of the `Team 2`) can see his own records as well as the records of the Users `Y1` and `Y2`.
- Manager `A` cannot see the records of `Team 2`.
- Manager `B` cannot see the records of `Team 1`.

I created `Team 1` and `Team 2` as Groups using `Settings --> Users and Companies --> Groups` and I affected the users and the managers to their respective groups but nothing happened. When I created a new event, it was still visible for all the others.

Do I need to add a special record rule or something?

I am using the `Events` module of `Odoo 12`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, groups are defined to have different permissions(read,write,delete,edit) on model level (not on records level). For e.g, User,Manager,Director,Admin,etc. In your case, teams have same permission on event model but you only want subset of records to be visible to respective teams. (I am curious if there is a term for such permission) So, you have to use record rule.

First, add new field `team_id` in user.
Then, add record rule to make event only visible to respective teams. `[('create_uid.team_id', '=', user.team_id.id)]`

[image]